# React Native Notify - Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection

Tags: react-native, push-notification, notifications

I just followed the Native Notify website for implementing notifications in React Native.

I'm testing it with Expo start in iOS device. First, I registered my Push Token. Then tried to send notifications and I can see the notifications in my device.

However, when I try to send a data object a problem occurs. I followed exactly the indications, and my App.js looks like in the example:

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { getPushDataObject } from "native-notify";
import registerNNPushToken from "native-notify";

export default function App() {
  registerNNPushToken(7141, "Xy4gdSRWQlE1DUBmwuS3x0");

  let pushDataObject = getPushDataObject();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(pushDataObject);
  }, [pushDataObject]);

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Hello world.</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

When sending data in the notification, I get the data printed out in the console but also this warn:

```
 WARN  Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
Error: Another async call to this method is in progress. Await the first Promise.
Error: Another async call to this method is in progress. Await the first Promise.
    at construct (native)
    at apply (native)
    at _construct (http://100.64.1.14:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false:3348:28)
    at Wrapper (http://100.64.1.14:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false:3310:25)
    at construct (native)
    at _createSuperInternal (http://100.64.1.14:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false:96959:322)
    at call (native)
    at CodedError (http://100.64.1.14:19000/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false:96967:26)
```

I first implemented it in an app with already Expo notifications system and got the same message, so I tried from 0 in a newly created app. Which Promise is it referring to? How can await that Promise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use it like this

```
import registerNNPushToken, {getPushDataObject} from 'native-notify';
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {Text, View} from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  registerNNPushToken(7141, 'Xy4gdSRWQlE1DUBmwuS3x0');
  const [pushDataObject, setPushData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    myfunction();
    if (pushDataObject != null) {
      console.log(pushDataObject);
    }
  }, [pushDataObject]);

  const myfunction = async () => {
    let data = await getPushDataObject();
    setPushData(data);
  };
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Hello world.</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

the issue with your code was you were calling getPushDataObject without async and await.